# Why does [=]{} have a lambda capture?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, language-lawyer, function-pointers

At an intuitive level, it makes sense that a lambda that needs to carry no state (through a reference or otherwise) should be cleanly convertible to a naked function pointer. However, I was recently surprised to see the following failing in GCC, Clang, and MSVC:

```
int main(int, char *[]) {
    void (*fp)() = []{}; // OK
  //fp = [=]{};          // XXX - no user defined conversion operator available
  //fp = [&]{};          // XXX - same ...
}
```

The C++17 spec (or at least [visible public draft version N4713](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf)), refers in item 7 of § 8.4.5.1 *[expr.prim.lambda.closure]* to lambdas with and without captures:

> The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression **with no lambda-capture** whose constraints (if any) are satisfied has a conversion function to pointer to function with C++ language linkage (10.5) having the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s function call operator. ...

However, looking into the formal grammar you can see the following in § 8.4.5 *[expr.prim.lambda]*:

> - ***lambda-expression*** :
>
>   - ***lambda-introducer*** compound-statement
>   - ...
> - ***lambda-introducer*** :
>
>   - [ ***lambda-capture<sub>opt</sub>*** ]
> - ...

and in § 8.4.5.2 *[expr.prim.lambda.capture]*:

> - ***lambda-capture*** :
>
>   - ***capture-default***
>   - *capture-list*
>   - *capture-default, capture-list*
> - ***capture-default*** :
>
>   - ***&***
>   - ***=***

So all the compilers were actually obeying the letter of the law to my dismay...

Why does the language define the existence of a capture as a narrow grammatical distinction in the declaration instead of basing it on whether the body contains references to any non-static/captured state?

Comment: You're assuming `[=]` and `[&]` don't capture `fp` which they do.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Why would they capture `fp` when it's not used in the body?

Comment: I think the way it's specified in the current standards text is just the way that was easiest to write down. I could turn this around and ask you why you're using `[=]` when you clearly don't actually want to capture anything.

Comment: @Brian This is clearly a contrived minimal example. My real use case involves a variadic perfect forwarding function that returns a lambda, which is examined elsewhere after being wrapped in a type-erasure class for being stateful or not. The workaround is internally testing on sizeof...(args) and yielding one of two nearly identical lambda bodies, but it's an ugly pattern.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The change that allowed the conversion was initiated by a national body comment. See [n3052: Converting Lambdas to Function Pointers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3052.html) which refers to national body [comment UK 42](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3086.html#UK42):

> A lambda with an empty capture list has identical semantics to a regular function type. By requiring this mapping we get an efficient lambda type with a known API that is also compatible with existing operating system and C library functions.

and the resolution from `N3052` was:

> Resolution: Add a new paragraph: "A lambda expression with an empty capture set shall be convertible to pointer to function type R(P), where R is the return type and P is the parameter-type-list of the lambda expression." Additionally it might be good to (a) allow conversion to function reference and (b) allow extern "C" function pointer types.
>
> ...
>
> Add a new paragraph after paragraph 5. The intent of this edit is to obtain a closure-to-function-pointer conversion for a lambda with no lambda-capture.
>
> > The closure type for a lambda-expression with no lambda-capture has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure type's function call operator. The value returned by this conversion function shall be the address of a function that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type's function call operator.

and that is where we are today. Note the comment said *empty capture list* and what we have today seems to match the intent as worded in the comment.

It looks like it was a fix based on a national body comment and was applied narrowly.

Answer (score 4):

The rule you propose would be extremely fragile, especially in the pre-P0588R1 world when implicit captures depended on odr-use.

Consider:

```
void g(int);
void h(const int&);

int my_min(int, int);

void f(int i) {
    const int x = 1, y = i;
    [=]{ g(x); }; // no capture, can convert?
    [=]{ g(y); }; // captures y
    [=]{ h(x); }; // captures x
    [=]{ my_min(x, 0); }; // no capture, can convert?
    [=]{ std::min(x, 0); }; // captures x
}
```

Comment: But apparently fragility was not a problem at that time, since the specification for lambda in default argument used the fragile rule: `void f() { const int x = 1; void a1(int = [=]{ return x; }()); /* <- OK, no capture */ void a2(int = [=]{ return *&x; }()); /* <- Error */ }` :/

Comment: I could pretend to care about that being too fragile if for the whole history of C++, all programmers were not exposed to that exact fragility without anyone in the committee apparently caring.

Comment: @cpplearner Local function declarations are rare; local function declarations with a default argument even rarer; local function declarations with a default argument that uses a lambda even more so.

Comment: @cpplearner Fragility was never a problem when programmers were expected to correctly use much more simple, beginners-oriented features like inline functions `const int x = 1; inline int f() { return x; } /* <- OK */ inline int g() { return *&x; } /* <- ill formed no diag required */` (if included in multiple TU)